# Django RegexValidator pattern for ZZ-99-ZZ-9999

Tags: regex, django

Trying to make a regex pattern in pattern ZZ-99-ZZ-9999 (2 capital character-2 numbers-2 capital character-4 numbers)

bus_number_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\W{2}-?1?\d{2}-?1?\W{2}-?1?\d{4}$',message="Bus number must be entered in the format: 'ZZ-99-ZZ-9999'"." ZZ must be in Capital.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[A-Z]{2}` - matches two upper cased letters. `[0-9]{4}` matches four digits. `-` is special character, so you need to type `\-`... So `[A-Z]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[A-Z]{2}\-[0-9]{4}` should be your regex.